# Make less-rails add line numbers as comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, asset-pipeline, less-rails

Is there any way to configure [`less-rails`](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) so that it shows the line number of original sources as comments? And is it possible to enable source mapping?

Consider the following example:

**file1.less**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

**file2.less**

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**application.css.less**

```css
@import "file1";
@import "file1";
```

**What I get:**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**What I want**

```css
/* file1.less line: 1 */
body {
  background-color: black;
}

/* file2.less line: 1 */
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Or is there any other easier way to find out which rule belongs to which file?

**Update**

When configuring my application, the `config.less` only contains the following:

```
{:paths=>
  [#<Pathname:/home/yan-foto/.../vendor/less>,
   #<Pathname:/home/yan-foto/.../node_modules/bootstrap-datetimepicker>,
   #<Pathname:/home/yan-foto/.../node_modules/bootstrap-slider>],
 :compress=>false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/parser.rb` file and replace (around line 54):

```
  end
  @parser = Less::JavaScript.exec { Less['Parser'].new(env) }
```

with:

```
  end
  env['dumpLineNumbers'] = 'comments';
  @parser = Less::JavaScript.exec { Less['Parser'].new(env) }
```

<strike>Based on https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails#configuration you should try:</strike>

```
MyProject::Application.configure do
  config.less.line-numbers << "comments"
  config.less.compress = true
end
```

When the preceding works as expected you could also consider to use CSS sourcemaps:

```
MyProject::Application.configure do
  config.less.source-map = true
  config.less.source-map-map-inline = true
end
```

> I really don't find the line config.less.line-numbers << "comments" in
>   docs

I fact my answer is only a suggestion and i was not able to test it. The above suggest that you are able to set some option for the Less compiler.

You can also find this option by running `lessc` without any argument:

```
-------------------------- Deprecated ----------------
  --line-numbers=TYPE      Outputs filename and line numbers.
                           TYPE can be either 'comments', which will output
                           the debug info within comments, 'mediaquery'
                           that will output the information within a fake
                           media query which is compatible with the SASS
                           format, and 'all' which will do both.
  --verbose                Be verbose.
```

> and I am sure that it has a syntax error because of the dash between line 
>   and numbers

I bet you are right about that. You should possible use: `config.less.dumpLineNumbers` and `config.less.sourceMap`

Or in your `config.less`: `:dumpLineNumbers>comments`

Comment: I really don't find the line `config.less.line-numbers << "comments"` in docs and I am sure that it has a syntax error because of the dash between `line` and `numbers`. Where is this mysterious line coming from?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I've been through the whole source, read the `lessc` docs, and so on. Still I have found no working solution. And with all due respect, your answer is really speculative.

Comment: > your answer is really speculative. Yes indeed. i was hoping it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am misunderstanding something with `rails-less`. Anyhow I appreciate your help.

Comment: I really don't feel comfortable changing gem sources but you are one of the best people around here! Thanks for investing so much time!